# WordPress User specific content in admin panel

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create a way to deliver a custom, user specific report in a custom page INSIDE the Admin panel of WordPress.

I was thinking that I would create content for each client and restrict it so that only that person could view it. I just can't figure out the code.

Answer (score 0):

You create a custom template and you should integrate the post that are depend on the current user's post. So, only the current user will see his/her posts on the page.

[How to create a custom template?](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/creating-custom-page-template-in-wordpress/)

[How to get current user posts?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/184760/how-to-get-the-current-user-post-and-its-id)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to post your question on WordPress Development and make sure to read codex website as it gives most of the code(examples of what you're looking for) you might need.

You need to create different user roles,

https://wedevs.com/98266/add-custom-user-roles-wordpress/